# Qlikview - sum in expression

Tags: charts, sum, qlikview

I have bar chart with dimension State,
and I need to get sum of Amount group by item,location.

I create bar chart, set dimension State,
and try to use dimension like

```
=sum(aggr(Amount,Item,Location))
```

and only if I select State I get bar chart for selected state.
But I want to have all state in bar chart with sum of amount...

now I have only no data to display.

In sql I use

```
select state, sum(Amount)
  from MyTable
  group by Item,Location
```

I need barchart with dimension state and expressions amount gropu by item,location

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the end result is that you're after - do you want a stacked bar chart with one bar per state, each of which is split into items? If so, just add Item as a second dimension and select stacked under Presentation.

Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're after. However, in general you'd expect to have something like: `sum(aggr(sum(Amount),Item,Location))` rather than what you have - the first parameter of the aggr is the calculation you want aggregating and the rest are what you want it aggregated by.

Comment: i want next in sql ihave select state,sum(Amount) from MyTable group by item,location

Comment: you will have to explain it better. Firstly, what are you getting with your sql query? I'd say you cannot select "state" if it is not in the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, to get this in a bar chart, you could use dimensions `Item` and `Location` and then set the bar chart expression to `sum(Amount)`. You can then make a selection in the `State` field to get the appropriate chart for that state. Depending on how many items you have in your data and how many locations, this may not be a very readable chart.

If you need bar charts for each state to be generated, you could try enabling a Trellis chart by clicking the Trellis button on the dimensions tab and checking the 'Enable Trellis Chart' checkbox. When you do this, the first dimension will become the trellis dimension, so for this, you'll want three dimensions: `State`, `Item`, and `Location` in that order. The problem with the trellis chart is that it's ugly and completely impractical for large samples.